# Any tips for aligning existing sprite sheets to a grid?

Tags: 2d, animation, sprites, spritesheet

I've been dabbling with sprites, and I've found most sprite sheets that have been posted for existing games (for example, Sonic & Knuckles) are not aligned to a grid.

[image: non-grid aligned Knuckles spritesheet]

I've found this frustrating when trying to use these sheets to set up animations in Unity. I managed to align the spritesheet above manually, but it took a while and I'm wondering if anyone has tips on how to make this process easier/faster?

Comment: When working on sprites with GameMaker, I too had to manually align them to a max rectangle covering the whole animation, so that the sprite origin was always on top of such rectangle. To minimize the amount of work, I treated upper body and legs as separated entities, but that's it. I'm not sure there's an automated tool out there, apart from hiring an artist to make them arrange animation frames accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your example, the frames are divided into unequal parts, but they have a pivot poitn down the center. Unity has the ability to create frames automatically

[image]